# How to debug infinite loop "crash" in Xcode for iOS involving CALayer and view layout during search?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, calayer

My app is hanging during search in a table view.

For what it's worth, the view hierarchy is very complex, there are popovers involved as well as filters and search bars etc. I am reviewing all those possibilities.

But the non-crash - it's an infinite loop - occurs when the search results table is being displayed / updated, after a call to `reloadData`.

Here is what I get when I stop the program and look at the main thread:

[image]

You can see - it involves UIView, CALayer, CATransaction. I have no clue how to get back to my controller classes to find the offending code.

Any hints, suggestions, wild guesses welcome!

**EDIT**  Here is more - some more classes appearing when I interrupt at some other random point.

[image]

Comment: at the time of reload data,check the datasource array ,how it behaves

Comment: Thank you. That's would be an obvious one. I don't think that a faulty datasource would result in the above loop.

Comment: Yeah may be because the datasource methods creates the cells and I can see a lot of CALayer,UIScrollView methods in that

Comment: Thanks for your time -- not helpful.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but in case other folks arrive here: it's *possible* you're facing a layout feedback loop. I wrote an article about how to debug these (link: [Debugging Auto Layout feedback loops](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/59/debugging-auto-layout-feedback-loops)) but here's a summary:

- If you modify your layouts during layout, or if you have ambiguous layout, you might find yourself stuck in a loop.
- Apple discussed a special debugging technique [at WWDC 2016](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/) – skip to about 15 minutes before the end, and they introduce the layout feedback loop debugger.
- To try it yourself, add `-UIViewLayoutFeedbackLoopDebuggingThreshold 100` to the list of launch arguments for your app, then run it again.
- When the error happens next time, you should get (a lot of) debugging information that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro, It really helped me. Fom yesterday I was banging my head against wall..